# Starting myproxy-server (via systemctl): Job for myproxy-server.service failed

Tags: globus-toolkit

While configuring myproxy in the context of Globus toolkit, I get the  error:

```
Starting myproxy-server (via systemctl):  
Job for myproxy-server.service failed. See 'systemctl status myproxy-server.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
 [FAILED]
```

How should I go about debugging this?

Comment: What does `systemctl status myproxy-server.service` output and is there anything interesting in `journalctl -xn`?

Comment: @Dmitri I solved that problem, now while running command "myproxy-logon -s root " it is frequently giving error that "Unknown host "root"
Unable to connect to root". Though myproxy server starts properly Whats wrong with this..??

Comment: Sorry Peter I cannot answer your question. Since you have made a considerable progress from your original post, perhaps you could post another question on this site or onto [gt-user mailing list](https://lists.globus.org/mailman/listinfo/gt-user).